# Updating SQL Table with input from another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables on a Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Instance.

Table#1

| deviceid | string1 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234ALT | 30.06.24 |
| 2 | 1234ALT | 30.06.24 |

Table#2

| deviceid | string1 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |

Table#2 has a lot more columns but for my usecase I only need these 3

Now I need a query that matches the deviceid from table1 to table2 and inserts the values for string1 and date from table1 into table2

The origin of table1 is an Excel file I already inserted in to a new table to make it easier to import. If I would try

```
update table2
set string1 = (select string1 
               from table1
               where table2.deviceid = table1.deviceid)
where table2.deviceid = table1.deviceid
```

and do the same for the date column would this work?

Comment: Would it work? Did you try it and see? And have you come across table aliases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.string1 = t1.string1,
t2.Date = t1.Date
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.deviceid = t1.deviceid;
```